# Remove index.php from CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter 2.2.0, and AppServ 2.5.10 as local server.
In the config.php I'm sure from: $config['index_page'] = '';
And this is the .htaccess in the root folder (nursing):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /nursing/

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

When I try to go to: localhost/nursing/welcome/index, the AppServ welcome page appeared!, not the welcome controller as it should be!

Comment: try to put this `.htaccess` to /nursing/.htaccess and change RewriteBase to / (instead /nursing/)

Answer (score 0):

My .htaccess here:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|templates|payment\.php)
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The system really have the module installed?
This code have in my ambient of production and work
Verify.

Answer (score 0):

The mod rewrite module was disables from httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```