# .htaccess doesn't support inserting data on codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an .htaccess file on my server (using codeigniter)

This is my view page

```
<form action='cms/register' method ='post'>
bla bla bla
</form>
```

and the contoller-model as everybody know 
the problem is when I click submit nothing happen 
but if I change the form heading to be like that

```
<form action='cms/index.php/register' method='post'>
```

evreything works so the problem is from the .htaccess.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, I'd strongly recommend that you took a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). If you are certain it's a .htaccess issue, then why not include the .htaccess code in your question?

Comment: sorry this is my htacces

Comment: i'm new instackover i don't know how to do that

Comment: Edit your question and paste in the htaccess code at the bottom.

Comment: That's why I recommended that you had a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) It will introduce you to how SO works and help you out :)

Comment: this is my htaccess link - the first one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016593/remove-index-php-from-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic urls like this:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

And then in the form:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url("register"); ?>">
```

If [site_url()](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) not working then try [base_url()](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html).

**Update:**

Copied from application/config/config.php, change `'index.php'` to `''`  from `$config['index_page']` if you are using mod_rewrite.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```